# Blazor default template fails with HTTP Error 502.5 with .NET Core 2.1 SDK RTM

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

If you have installed .NET Core 2.1 SDK, when running a solution with the "ASP.NET Core Web Application" template using the "Blazor (ASP.NET Core Hosted)" project type the client app fails to load displaying the error:

```
HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure
```

Answer (score 2):

This issue is reported on the [Blazor GitHub issue 1424](https://github.com/aspnet/Blazor/issues/1424) but do not do as suggested and delete your global.json file.

The solution is to modify your global.json file to have your installed SDK version.

I've got dotnet 2.1.3 installed and 2.1.300 uin my Balzor project's global.json file, and am getting the same error

It turns out I've got '2.1.500-preview-009297' of the dotnet SDK!

To find the highest version of the dot net SDK run this script in the Powershell ISE:

```
$runtimes = [Collections.Generic.List[string]];
$runtimes = (ls "$env:programfiles/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App").Name
$runtime = $runtimes[$runtimes.Length-1]
$runtime
cd $env:programfiles/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App
cd $runtime
dotnet --version
```

copy and paste the last string into your global.json file:

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "highest sdk version"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The template for the Server project currently references the 2.1.0-preview2-final of Microsoft.AspNetCore.App, which does not restore since the RTM.

As a workaround until the project template is updated, edit the Server .csproj file, remove the **`-preview2-final`** suffix so that this line:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.1.0-preview2-final" />
```

reads

```
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.1.0" />
```

and then ***rebuild the solution.***